# Sapui5 * or /../ Path operator

Tags: json, binding, operator-keyword, aggregation, sapui5

I have a JSON with this structure:

```
{  
  "collection": [  
    {  
      "category": "Cables",
      "catId": "B"
        items": {  
          "subcat": [  
            {  
              "subcatname": "Good quality",
              "products": [  
                {  
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "cable",
                  "price": "1400",
                  "image": "resources/pic(1).jpg",
                  "title": "Lorem Ipsum ",
                  "description": "Lorem Ipsum ."
                },
             (...)

      "category": "Other",
      "catId":"B"
             (...)
```

There are multiple categories and subcategories. My problem is that when creating a search mechanism I need to bind all lowest elements in the hierarchy to a List. At the moment im doing it like this:

```
var sList = new sap.m.List({
    id: "searchListId",
    columns: [
        (...)
    ]
});

var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    type: sap.m.ListType.Active,
    cells: [
        new sap.m.Image({
            src: "{products>subcatname}",
            width: "100%"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
            width: "100%",
            text: "{products>name} \n {flatProducts>price}"
        }),
    ]

});

sList.bindAggregation("items", "products>/collection/1/items/subcat/0/product", oTemplate);
```

But this solution only displays a small part of the JSON, I've checked fo a * or /../ operator but neither works. Is there a similar one i could input into the path so it would search for all the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing this directly in UI5.

You will have to manipulate your JSON or create a new JSON(Model) that only contains the leafs. With this new model you can do a regular list binding. To manipulate the JSON structure Qualiture is totally right pointing to [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

BR
Chris

Comment: I have tried that, and it displays the correct items now. But in this case i loose the path information and i dont know how to route to appropriate detail after clicking on the list item

Comment: You could store the original path in your newly created JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/), IIRC it also searches through a multidimensional array